# About behavior of "Minimize" in case of Remote App when using Guacamole

Tags: windows, go, rdp, guacamole

We are using Guacamole for developing an application with RDP. We did POC using code from the following GitHub repositories:

https://github.com/wwt/guac
https://github.com/wwt/guac-vue

Configuration details are:

- Windows Server 2016. RDP service is running here.

With this setup, we could successfully access the application remotely, however, the "minimize" action is not behaving as we expected. That is, the remote app window vanishes when we press the "minimize" button and a black screen is shown.
[image]
We could get back to the app by pressing 'Alt+Tab' combination but what we are expecting here is that the app getting placed at the bottom of the window showing three buttons: "Minimize, Restore and Close", so that we can take the further action. (As shown below.)
[image]

Has someone come across such a scenario and was able to address the need? Any help will be highly appreciated.
We came across [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@guacamole.apache.org/msg09246.html) thread that talks about a similar problem but it doesn't have a solution.
We also explored [official documentation of guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html) but had no luck.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are starting the application using RemoteApp mechanism. The RemoteApp means that the remote application will be started integrated with the local computer desktop. The local computer desktop, or better window manager, will handle the minimise action.

In case of the Guacamole, the "local computer desktop" is the browser window, which does not have window manager. This means that there is no place for app to go when minimised.

You may try the Guacamole parameter "initial-program" instead of "remote-app". This parameter will launch the application immediately upon the connection is established, but the session will also have full desktop from the remote machine.